# How to convert rows to columns with commasepart using huge data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to convert rows to columns with comma-separated data using bulk data?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp]
(
    [eid] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [money] NULL,
    [doj] [date] NULL,
    [deptno] [int] NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [name], [sal], [doj], [deptno]) 
VALUES (1, N'a', 100.0000, CAST(N'2010-10-01' AS Date), 10)

INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [name], [sal], [doj], [deptno]) 
VALUES (2, N'bb', 200.0000, CAST(N'2010-02-03' AS Date), 20)

INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [name], [sal], [doj], [deptno]) 
VALUES (3, N'c', 300.0000, CAST(N'2017-02-03' AS Date), 30)

INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [name], [sal], [doj], [deptno]) 
VALUES (4, N'd', 301.0000, CAST(N'2010-03-04' AS Date), 10)

INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [name], [sal], [doj], [deptno]) 
VALUES (5, N'teee', 250.0000, CAST(N'2010-06-04' AS Date), 20)

INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [name], [sal], [doj], [deptno]) 
VALUES (7, N'tte', 800.0000, CAST(N'2010-08-09' AS Date), 70)
```

I want output like below :

```
userlist
1,2,3,4,5,7
```

I tried this code:

```
select distinct  
    stuff((select ',' + cast(u.eid as varchar)
           from emp u
           where 1 = 1
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as userlist
from emp
```

Suppose if data has 100 thousand entries, then this query is not returning 100 thousand comma-separated

Could you please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I think the query is working as expected.  But the result is too large to be displayed in management studio.